# Wagner's trick to monitor FindRoot no longer works in Mathematica version 8

Tags: evaluation, monitoring

I recently learned that we can use `Print` as a monitoring tool.  My favorite is Ted Ersek's [example](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_11.html)

```
h[f1[a1], f2[e][a2]] /. (a_ /; Print[a] :> 0)
```

which reveals the order in which `ReplaceAll` goes through parts of an expression.  Clearly this is a very useful trick.

On page 41 of his [book](http://amzn.com/007912237X), David Wagner gave the example

```
FindRoot[Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, .5}]
```

which prints the sequence of iterates generated by `FindRoot` along the way.  That code no longer works on Mathematica version 8:

```
In[22]:= FindRoot[Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, .5}]
During evaluation of In[22]:= x
Out[22]= {x -> 0.785398}
```

At first I thought this is related to the fact that we now have the `EvaluationMonitor` option, and `FindRoot` somehow weeds out superfluous subexpressions like `Print`.  Now I know this is probably false because

```
Plot[Print[x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}]
```

still lists all the points considered during its evaluation.

**Why does `FindRoot` ignore `Print`?**

Comment: I've learned recently that `Plot`, probably as well as `FindRoot` don't necessarily evaluate the whole first argument, as is, in every iteration. They sometimes partially evaluate first, and I am not sure in what cases. So you probably simply shouldn't put there what you want evaluated every time. Probably since `EvaluationMonitor` exists they have taken the liberty to put some optimizations in the expression preprocessing, where they felt like it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the `Evaluated -> False` option:

```
FindRoot[Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> False]
```

> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398
>
> Out[3]= {x -> 0.785398}

As to the `Plot`, try

```
Plot[Print[x]; Sin[x], {x, Pi/4, Pi/2}, Evaluated -> True];
```

> During evaluation of In[5]:= x

As you see, the behavior is exactly the same as it is for `FindRoot` by default. The difference in default behavior can be explained by default values of the `Evaluated` option:

```
Options[#, Evaluated] & /@ {Plot, FindRoot}
```

> {{Evaluated -> Automatic}, {Evaluated -> True}}

It seems that the `Automatic` value is equivalent to `False` in this case.

### Another approach

As Albert Retey mentioned in the comment, the "standard" (and documented) way to monitor evaluations is to define objective function as black-box function by restricting its argument to numerical values only:

```
In[1]:= f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x])
FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}]
```

> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.5
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.793408
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 0.785398
>
> Out[2]= {x -> 0.785398}

### Additional comparisons

Here I switch off autocompilation for not loading the corresponding package (it affects output of `Trace`):

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, x]; f[x_] := x - 1;
Trace[FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> False, Compiled -> False], 
  TraceInternal -> True] // LeafCount
Trace[FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> True, Compiled -> False], 
  TraceInternal -> True] // LeafCount
```

> Out[2]= 181
>
> Out[3]= 111

```
In[4]:= ClearAll[f, x]; f[x_?NumericQ] := x - 1;
Trace[FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> False, Compiled -> False], 
  TraceInternal -> True] // LeafCount
Trace[FindRoot[f[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> True, Compiled -> False], 
  TraceInternal -> True] // LeafCount
```

> Out[5]= 217
>
> Out[6]= 261

One can see that in simple cases the option `Evaluated -> True` reduces number of evaluations but in more complicated cases (black-box function) it cannot help.

Comment: `Evaluated` is not listed as one of the options for `FindRoot` in the documentation.  What does it do?

Comment: It controls whether the first argument will be evaluated before the moment when the local variable (in this case `x`) will have concrete value assigned. See [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_frm/thread/21e4e427b0eff534/9ce4c9359cb2819d#9ce4c9359cb2819d) Mathgroups thread for more information.

Comment: It probably should be mentioned that the "standard" trick to provide a function which only evalutes for numeric arguments (`f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x])`) will also do the trick without the need of the undocumented option.

Comment: It also works for `Plot`. Nice one! +1

Comment: @AlbertRetey I think you should post an answer with that. May help others.

Comment: @AlbertRetey I am not sure I understand how that trick works in this context.  Could you post an answer based on that?

Comment: @Michael I updated the answer with the "standard" technique mentioned by Albert Retey.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks!  Could you also include a link to the documentation where that "standard" trick is explained?  I apologize for making so many requests of you.

Comment: @Michael This technique is demonstrated in the Documentation in few places, for example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodMinimum.html).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I only wished all, and not just the first argument could be evaluated by Evaluated. Then Plot etc. could be constructed easier programatically.

Comment: @Rolf Please compare outputs of ``Clear["`*"]; x = y; FindRoot[x, {y, .5}]`` and ``Clear["`*"]; y = x; FindRoot[x, {y, .5}]``. You will see that in the first case everything is OK but in the second case `FindRoot` cannot understand that `y==x`. It means that `FindRoot` does not evaluate the second argument even with default option `Evaluated -> True`. Note also that these functions (`Plot`, `FindRoot` etc.) have attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov sure. I just wondered why this is the case. It should not, unless there is a good reason. Maybe WRI can still change the behaviour before it gets documented?

Comment: @Rolf Now I see you point. I think that current behavior with not evaluating the second argument is correct and expected: it is mentioned in the Documentation that "`FindRoot` first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates `f` with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically." It means that the second argument (at least the variable istself) must *not* be evaluated because it should be localized: "`FindRoot` has attribute `HoldAll`, and effectively uses `Block` to localize variables." So I am sure that this aspect will not be changed.

Comment: @Rolf I updated the answer with additional comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

First, it's probably worth adding to [@Rojo's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/wagners-trick-to-monitor-findroot-no-longer-works-in-mathematica-version-8/156768#comment18760_6589) that `EvaluationMonitor` was introduced in V5, so that the functionality of Wagner's code can be achieved with

```
FindRoot[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, .5}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]]
```

Second, note that using `Evaluated -> False` or `?NumericQ` prevents symbolic analysis of the function and prevents `FindRoot` from choosing Newton's method, as is done in Wagner's book. In his book, the output of `Print` is

```
x
0.5
0.793408
0.785398
0.785398
```

To get the essential part of Wagner's output with `Evaluated -> False` or a `?NumericQ` function supply the `Jacobian`:

```
FindRoot[Print[x]; Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, .5}, Evaluated -> False, 
 Jacobian -> D[{Sin[x] - Cos[x]}, {{x}}]]
(*
  0.5
  0.793408
  0.785398
  0.785398

  {x -> 0.785398}
*)
```

Note the initial `x` is missing, but otherwise the steps are the same.

Just because I like generalizing processes:  Here's a generic wrapper, with a debugging hook `debug` that can be set to `Print` temporarily with [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).

```
ClearAll[dbFunc];
f[x_] := Sin[x] - Cos[x];
dbFunc[f_][x_?NumericQ] := (debug[x]; f[x]);
Derivative[1][dbFunc[f_]][x_] := f'[x]; (* need to Clear[Derivative] to undo this def *)
Block[{debug = Print},
 FindRoot[dbFunc[f][x], {x, .5}]
 ]
(*
  0.5
  0.793408
  0.785398
  0.785398

  {x -> 0.785398}
*)
```