# How to work out the parameter in a definite integration which has an exact value while the integration doesn't have an analytical solution?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

Here is the equation I'm trying to solve:

```
NIntegrate[1/(E^(1/(λ T)) - 1), {λ, 200, 220}] == 1000
```

`T` is the parameter I'm trying to work out. I tried to solve it with `InverseFunction[]` but it seemed not to work:

```
te[ii_] := InverseFunction[NIntegrate[1/(-1 + E^(1/(# λ))), {λ, 200, 220}] &][ii]
Evaluate[te[1000]]
```

What's wrong with my solution? How to correct it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a slight improvement of b.gatessucks's answer, adding a (mostly effective) initial guess:

```
te[ii_?NumericQ, opts___] := (\[FormalCapitalT] /. First@FindRoot[
     NIntegrate[1/(E^(1/(λ \[FormalCapitalT])) - 1), {λ, 200, 220}] == ii,
         {\[FormalCapitalT], (0.5437727672315316 + ii (0.5440978395984463 + 
                             ii (0.12244298721801757 + (0.009523809523809525 + 
                             0.0002380952380952381 ii) ii)))/(476.1910924718744 +
                             ii (247.61910924718742 + ii (30. + ii)))}, 
            Evaluated -> False, opts])
```

Here's how I obtained the initial guess:

```
PadeApproximant[InverseSeries[
    Integrate[#, {λ, 200, 220}] & /@ 
      Normal[Series[1/(E^(1/(λ ii)) - 1), {ii, Infinity, 7}]] + O[ii, Infinity]^8],
                {ii, Infinity, 4}] // N // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Wow, what a advanced solution…Er, I wonder where I can find the introduction of `Evaluated`, I can't find it in the help, and, it seems that `PadeApproximant` here isn't necessary, why you choose it?

Comment: The `Evaluated` option is indeed undocumented, but it has been discussed a lot on this site; search around. As for `PadeApproximant[]`, it's for generating a **rational** function approximation; they tend to be more accurate than truncations of Taylor polynomials for the same amount of arithmetic operations.

Comment: For example [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/wagners-trick-to-monitor-findroot-no-longer-works-in-mathematica-version-8)? OK, it's very interesting, now…I'm sorry! But I still can't understand the independent variable `opts___` which I thought I would make it out after I knew the meaning of Evaluated…

Comment: The `opts` is for the case where you need to pass options to `FindRoot[]`. Now that I think about it, I should have also made provisions for passing options to `NIntegrate[]`... maybe later.

Comment: So, here I can just remove it? (Trying…) ………er, it seems that the `?NumericQ` and `Evaluated`(whether it's True or False) are both unnecessary now…

Comment: Well, you can certainly do `te[ii_?NumericQ] := (* stuff *)` and remove the `opts` within the definition, but the `Evaluated` is necessary; try it for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried:`te[ii_] := (FindRoot[
   NIntegrate[
     1/(E^(1/(\[Lambda] \[FormalCapitalT])) - 1), {\[Lambda], 200, 
      220}] == 
    ii, {\[FormalCapitalT], (0.5437727672315316 + 
       ii (0.5440978395984463 + 
          ii (0.12244298721801757 + (0.009523809523809525 + 
                0.0002380952380952381 ii) ii)))/(476.1910924718744 + 
       ii (247.61910924718742 + ii (30. + ii)))}]);
te[1000]` My version of mathematica is 8.0.4.

Comment: Are you sure? Try `Remove[te]` and execute your definition again, and try evaluating at some numerical argument.

Comment: Oh…I forget that te should be removed first 囧. Yeah, you are right, the Evaluated here is necessary. So, the `Evaluated` here stops the calculation of the expression with an unknown parameter, but why the `?NumericQ` doesn't work?

Comment: The `_?NumericQ` is *defensive programming*; even if you accidentally pass it something that is manifestly not a number, it won't foul up.

Comment: OK, this time I completely understand…I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `FindRoot` :

```
func[T_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[1/(E^(1/(\[Lambda] T)) - 1), {\[Lambda], 200, 220}]

sol = FindRoot[func[T] == 1000, {T, 0.1}]

(* {T -> 0.240468} *)

func[sol[[1, 2]]]

(* 1000. *)
```

`FindRoot` needs an initial guess for the unknown; you can get a rough estimate by plotting `func` for instance.

Comment: Maybe for this case the initial guess isn't that important since the te[ii] is actually monotonous?

Comment: @xzczd I agree.