# Complex Number Presentation and an issue with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, complex

First of all, I am not entirely sure what the problem is. The code I am presenting worked in a previous version of *Mathematica* but not now in Version 11.0.1. Essentially, I am calculating Point Spread Functions (PSF) according to the theory outlined by Born & Wolf.

```
 {λIll = 0.488, nIll = 1.518, NAIll = 1.3};
    optIll = {v -> 2 π n r Sin[α]/λ, 
   u -> 2 π n z Sin[α]^2/λ, α -> 
    ArcSin[NA/n], n -> nIll, λ -> λIll, 
   NA -> NAIll, ρ -> rho};
```

The integral is split into two parts. The factor `bwFIll` and the integrand `bwIIll` are simplified separately.

```
bwFIll = Function[{r, z}, 
  Evaluate@FullSimplify[-2.0 π I n Sin[α]^2/λ Exp[
       I u/Sin[α]^2] //. optIll, ass]]
```

Output

```
(* Function[{r, z}, (0. - 14.3343 I) E^((0. + 19.5448 I) z)] *)
```

Texte

```
bwIIll = Function[{r, z}, 
  Evaluate@FullSimplify[
    BesselJ[0, v ρ] Exp[-0.5 I u ρ^2] ρ //. optIll, 
    ass]]
```

Output

```
(*  Function[{r, z}, E^((0. - 7.16713 I) rho^2 z) rho BesselJ[0, 16.738 r rho]] *)
```

What drives me nuts is the presentation of the complex number as `0.0 - 7.16713 I` instead of as simply as `-7.16713 I`. This was different in my original Notebook. I cannot reproduce this but I still have the notebook.

```
bwFullIll[r_, z_] := 
 bwFIll[r, z] NIntegrate[bwIIll[r, z], {rho, 0.0, 1.0}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

Calling the function is fine.

```
bwFullIll0 = bwFullIll[0, 0]
```

Output

```
(* 0. - 7.16713 I  *)
```

This function calculates a scalar PSF.

```
illFull[r_, z_] := 
 Block[{uill}, uill = bwFullIll[r, z]/bwFullIll0; 
  Chop[uill Conjugate[uill]]]
```

However, this function `FindRoot` and other functions such as `NIntegrate` all produce the same error list.

```
illR0 = (x /. FindRoot[illFull[x, 0.0] == 0.0, {x, 0.22}])
```

Output

```
During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (1. +0. I) rho BesselJ[0,16.738 rho x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.}}.

During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (1. +0. I) rho BesselJ[0,16.738 rho x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.}}.

During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (1. +0. I) rho BesselJ[0,16.738 rho x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.}}.

During evaluation of In[9]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[9]= 0.228923
```

I have no clue what is going on and really need to know what is causing the error message. I should add that I experienced with various options `AccuracyGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` but to no avail. What works is the use of `Table`.

Comment: Define `illFull[r_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] ...` See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037 -- As for the display of complex numbers, that seems to be how it's done (and has been for a while, I think).  Reformatting output is possible, probably, but maybe not easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. This still leaves the issue with the way the (non-)complex numbers are presented.

Comment: The annoying issue is that `Chop` has no effect. The `0.` is shown independently of whether the real or the imaginary part are zero. I also had another look at an older notebook (2001, no idea which version I used then). The `r_?NumericQ`, which I have been using in other circumstances, was not required and the complex values reduced to the expected simpler values or are at least shown in simpler terms.

Comment: Running `bwFullIll0 = bwFullIll[0, 0] // Chop` returns `0. - 7.16713 I`. I.e. no effect of `Chop`.

Answer (score 2):

> The code I am presenting worked in a previous version of Mathematica but not now in Version 11.0.1.
>
> What drives me nuts is the presentation of the complex number as `0.0 - 7.16713 I` instead of as simply as `-7.16713 I`. This was different in my original Notebook.
>
> I also had another look at an older notebook (2001, no idea which version I used then).

In *Mathematica* version 8 was a change in how complex numbers are represented internally and displayed within the Notebook interface. Originally the representation was as you describe:

```
$Version
2. I
% // FullForm
Developer`PackedArrayQ@Developer`ToPackedArray[{1. + I, 1.1 I}]
```

> ```
> "5.2 for Microsoft Windows x86 (64 bit) (June 20, 2005)"
> 2. I
> Complex[0, 2.`]
> False
> ```

But now it is different:

```
$Version
2. I
% // FullForm
Developer`PackedArrayQ@Developer`ToPackedArray[{1. + I, 1.1 I}]
```

> ```
> "11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"
> 0. + 2. I    
> Complex[0.`, 2.`]
> True
> ```

This was an intentional change in order to allow packed arrays of complex numbers (according to a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/oSMXpzIBKZY/1_kT3-TrDeAJ) on [MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup) long time ago). In a [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GrAn2Omm9iM/82putOSJxroJ) an example of a code broken due to this change was given (I simplify it even further here):

```
fnc = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
fnc[(1. I)/I]
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 2}}, <>][1. + 0. I]

(in versions before version 8 the output was `1.`). As a workaround it was suggested to use `Chop`:

```
fnc[Chop[(1. I)/I]]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

---

But in your particular case the source of the problem is different: it is just preprocessing introduced in `FindRoot` which can be disabled using undocumented option `Evaluated -> False`:

```
illR0 = (x /. FindRoot[illFull[x, 0.0] == 0.0, {x, 0.22}, Evaluated -> False])
```

> ```
> 0.228921
> ```

See the following answers for more information:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6604/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/280

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Who knows maybe the change will be reverted one day.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer Please look at my answer again: I significantly extended it and at the bottom you'll find solution for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful in displaying complex numbers (no guarantees you won't find cases where this leads to incorrect results):

```
cleanComplexForm[expr_] := 
 expr /. Complex[r_, i_] /; PossibleZeroQ[r] :> i Defer[I]


E^((0.-7.16713 I) rho^2 z) rho BesselJ[0,16.738 r rho]//cleanComplexForm
(* E^(-7.16713 rho^2 z I) rho BesselJ[0,16.738 r rho] *)
```