# Jacobian of ParametricNDSolve and FindRoot for the Three Body Problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics

#### The main problem

I took the time to reformulate the question in a more appealing and concise way.

I want to find bifurcations of solutions to the [three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem). In order to do that, I define the [symplectic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix), the [Gravitational Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential) and the [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics):

```
(* Symplectic matrix *)
Clear[mJ]
mJ = ArrayFlatten[{{0, IdentityMatrix[9]}, {-IdentityMatrix[9], 0}}];

(* Gravitational potential *)
Clear[V]
V[x_, m_] := -((#1 - #2).(#1 - #2))^(-1/2) & @@@ Subsets[x, {2}].
    (#1 #2 & @@@ Subsets[m, {2}]);

(* Hamiltonian *)
Clear[H]
H[x_, p_, m_] := Total[p^2/(2 m), 2] + V[x,m];
```

The main problem is to find a periodic solution of

$$\label{E:HS}\pmatrix{\dot{x}\\\dot{p}} = J \nabla H,\tag{1}$$

where $x$ is the position vector and $p$ is the momentum vector, $J$ the symplectic matrix, and $H$ the Hamiltonian, and then chase it as one of the masses varies (the bifurcation parameter).

A remarkable solution for this system is the [Chenciner-Montgomery figure-8 solution](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011268):

[image: Chenciner-Montgomery figure-8 solution of the three body problem]

From this solution I'll be chasing the bifurcation.

Given the Hamiltonian structure of \eqref{E:HS}, a better numerical approach is to use its conserved quantities to extend (unfold) it in a proper way. In this case, the conserved quantities are the linear and angular momenta, along with the Hamiltonian itself. Accordingly, I define the Linear and Angular Momenta:

```
(* Linear momentum *)
P[p_] := Total@p;

(* Angular momentum *)
L[x_, p_] := Total@MapThread[Cross[#1, #2] &, {x, p}];
```

Next, I define the variables:

```
(* Variables *)
x = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};
p = {{px1, py1, pz1}, {px2, py2, pz2}, {px3, py3, pz3}};

(* Initial conditions *)
xI = {{xI1, yI1, zI1}, {xI2, yI2, zI2}, {xI3, yI3, zI3}};
pI = {{pxI1, pyI1, pzI1}, {pxI2, pyI2, pzI2}, {pxI3, pyI3, pzI3}};

(* Dummy variables *)
xD = {{x1D, y1D, z1D}, {x2D, y2D, z2D}, {x3D, y3D, z3D}};
pD = {{px1D, py1D, pz1D}, {px2D, py2D, pz2D}, {px3D, py3D, pz3D}};
```

The unfolded system is [(Doedel, et.al.)](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kokubu/RIMS2006references/ContPer3Body.pdf):

$$\begin{multline}\label{E:US} \pmatrix{\dot{x}\\ \dot{p}} = T \nabla H + \alpha \nabla H + \beta_1 \nabla P_x + \beta_2 \nabla P_y \\ + \beta_3 \nabla P_z + \lambda_1 \nabla L_x + \lambda_2 \nabla L_y + \lambda_3 \nabla L_z, \tag{2}\end{multline}$$

where we have rescaled time (in order to work in $0 \le t < 1$). Here, $T$ is the period, and $\alpha$, $\beta_i$, and $\lambda_i$ are the unfolding parameters.

The main purpose is to make the system [*dissipative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_system) in the direction of the central manifold (pretty clever, if you ask me). It can be shown that the solution of the extended system is a solution of the original system when all the folding parameter are equal to zero [(Muñoz-Almaraz, et.al.)](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kokubu/RIMS2006/ContPerHam.pdf).

So:

```
(* Unfolded Hamiltonian system *)
threeBSys = MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {D[Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[t]], t],
    (T mJ + a IdentityMatrix[18]).Grad[H[x, p, {m1, m2, m3}], 
    Flatten@{x, p}] + Total@Grad[MapThread[#1 #2 &, {{b1, b2, b3}, P[p]}], 
    Flatten@{x, p}] + Total@Grad[MapThread[#1 #2 &, {{L1, L2, L3}, L[x, p]}], 
    Flatten@{x, p}] /. Map[# -> #[t] &, Flatten@{x, p}]}];

(* Initial conditions equations *)
iC = MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[0]], Flatten@{xI, pI}}];
```

In order to study the bifurcation of the figure-8 solution to the 3-Body problem, I start with the appropriate coordinates:

```
(* Initial conditions for the figure 8 *)
{x0, p0} = {{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0.347111, 0.532728, 0},
    {0.347111, 0.532728, 0}, -2 {0.347111, 0.532728, 0}}};
T0 = 6.324449;
```

And then I define the [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)):

```
Clear[flow1, flowT]
(* Flow at t=1 *)
flow1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[Flatten@{threeBSys, iC},
    Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[1]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    Flatten@{xI, pI, T, m1, m2, m3, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta"}];

(* Flow for 0<t<1 *)
flowT = ParametricNDSolveValue[Flatten@{threeBSys, iC}, 
    Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[t]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    Flatten@{xI, pI, T, m1, m2, m3, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
    Method -> {"DAEInitialization" -> {"Collocation"}}];
```

Now I'm almost ready to chase the bifurcation with respect to mass `m1`. As seven extra folding parameters were added to the system, seven more equations must be added to close it. This are, of course, the conserved quantities. If $x_0$ is the starting point (initial condition), and $x_1$ is the point at time $t=1$, then, if $\varphi_t$ is the flow at time $t$,

$$\begin{align}
x_1 - \varphi_1(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla H(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla P_x(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla P_y(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla P_z(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla L_x(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla L_y(x_0) &= 0,\\
(x_1 - x_0)^T J \nabla L_z(x_0) &= 0,
\end{align}$$
where the first condition is the periodicity condition, the second is the conserved Hamiltonian condition, the third, fourth, and fifth conditions are the conserved linear momenta, and the sixth, seventh, and eighth conditions are the conserved angular momenta.

Now that I've closed the system, I'm ready to chase the bifurcation, but, first, I want to refine my initial point (where all masses are equal to $1$):

```
(* Fig-8 conditions refinement *)
{x0B, p0B, T0B, m1B, m2B, m3B, aB, b1B, b2B, b3B, L1B, L2B, L3B} =
 {xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} /. 
 FindRoot[Print[NumberForm[Norm@Flatten@{flow1 @@ 
 Flatten@{xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3} - Flatten@{xI, pI}}, 20]];
 Flatten@{flow1 @@ Flatten@{xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3} - 
 Flatten@{xI, pI}, Flatten[{xI, pI} - {x0, p0}].mJ.(Grad[H[x, p, {1., 1., 1.}], 
 Flatten@{x, p}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2&, {Flatten@{x, p}, Flatten@{x0, p0}}]), Total@(xI-x0),
 Flatten[{xI, pI} - {x0, p0}].mJ.# & /@ (Grad[L[x, p], Flatten@{x, p}] /.
 MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{x, p}, Flatten@{x0, p0}}])},
 MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {Flatten@{xI, pI, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
 Flatten@{x0, p0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}], Evaluated -> False];
```

The `Print` command allows me to see how the periodicity condition is behaving. This quickly yields the output

```
0.003405540054764908
0.003405540054764908
0.0034066427736885
0.003405540055840062
0.00340554005583874
0.003405540055840691
0.003405540054936841
0.003405540055896425
0.003405657294778178

FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point 
{xI1,yI1,zI1,xI2,yI2,zI2,xI3,yI3,zI3,pxI1,pyI1,pzI1,pxI2,pyI2,pzI2,pxI3,pyI3,pzI3,a,b1,b2,b3,L1,L2,L3} = 
{-1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.347111,0.532728,0.,0.347111,0.532728,0.,-0.694222,-1.06546,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}.
Try perturbing the initial point(s).
```

The option `Jacobian -> "FiniteDifferences"` doesn't do anything to help.

Very clumsily, I think, I define the Jacobian matrix using a wrapper for `flow1`:

```
(* Flow Wrapper *)
Clear[fWrap, solp]
solp = ParametricNDSolve[Flatten@{threeBSys, iC}, Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[1]], {t, 0, 1},
    Flatten@{xI, pI, T, m1, m2, m3, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 12];
fWrap[xEv__, pEv__, T_, m1_, m2_, m3_, aEv_, b1Ev_, b2Ev_, b3Ev_, L1Ev_, L2Ev_, L3Ev_] :=
    (# @@ Flatten@{xEv, pEv, T, m1, m2, m3, aEv, b1Ev, b2Ev, b3Ev, L1Ev, L2Ev, L3Ev} /.
    solp) & /@ ((#@1) & /@ Flatten@{x, p}) - Flatten@{xEv, pEv};

(* Jacobian Matrix *)
Clear[J]
J[xEv__, pEv__, T_, m1_, m2_, m3_, aEv_, b1Ev_, b2Ev_, b3Ev_, L1Ev_, L2Ev_, L3Ev_] :=
    D[Flatten@{ fWrap[xD, pD, T, m1, m2, m3, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D],
    Flatten[{xD, pD} - {xEv, pEv}].mJ.(Grad[H[xD, pD, {m1, m2, m3}], Flatten@{xD, pD}] /. 
    MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD}, Flatten@{xEv, pEv}}]),
    Total@(xD-xEv),Flatten[{xD, pD} - {xEv, pEv}].mJ.#&/@(Grad[L[xD, pD],Flatten@{xD, pD}]/. 
    MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD}, Flatten@{xEv, pEv}}])},
    {Flatten@{xD, pD, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D}}] /.
    MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D},
    Flatten@Flatten@{xEv, pEv, aEv, b1Ev, b2Ev, b3Ev, L1Ev, L2Ev, L3Ev}}]
```

(I do this to explicitly show the dimensions of `flow1` to `J`, otherwise I get mismatching dimensions errors.)

A brief test shows how inefficient this is:

```
In[1]:= Timing[J[x0B, p0B, T0, 1., 1., 1., aB, b1B, b2B, b3B, L1B, L2B, L3B]]
Out[1]:= {112.516, <<..>>}
```

But when I add the option `Jacobian -> J[xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3]]` to `FindRoot`, I end up with a very nice refinement:

```
In[2]:= Timing[FindRoot[<<..>>,
    Jacobian -> J[xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3]];

0.003405540054764908
9.17370958132291*10^(-6)
5.906750301560982*10^(-7)
1.535443284056098*10^(-11)
7.74379558359556*10^(-15)

Out[2]:= {826.234, {{{-0.999846, -5.68972*10^-6, 0.}, {0.999846, 5.68972*10^-6, 0.},
    {2.14173*10^-12, -3.2671*10^-12, 0.}}, {{0.347141, 0.532768, 0.},
    {0.347141, 0.532768, 0.}, {-0.694281, -1.06554, 0.}}, 6.32445,
    1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

#### Question 1

Is there a faster way to implement the Jacobian? I've tried to use `ND` with little succes

#### Question 2

How can I sow the Jacobian computed by `FindRoot`?

#### Question 3

In general, how can I improve the overall performance of the code?
(I'm not sure if I'm clogging the code somewhere with bad practice)

---

#### Update

Reading [How to work with Experimental`NumericalFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/1024), I've been able to define a remarkably faster Jacobian:

```
(* Numerical Jacobian *)
Clear[JN]
JN[xEv_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), pEv_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), 
    TEv_?NumericQ, m1Ev_?NumericQ, m2Ev_?NumericQ, m3Ev_?NumericQ, 
    aEv_?NumericQ, b1Ev_?NumericQ, b2Ev_?NumericQ, b3Ev_?NumericQ, 
    L1Ev_?NumericQ, L2Ev_?NumericQ, L3Ev_?NumericQ] := Module[{fluxWrap, smallJ, ppDim},
    ppDim = Length[Flatten@{xEv, pEv}];
    fluxWrap = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[
    Flatten@{xD, pD, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D}, 
    ParametricNDSolveValue[Flatten@{threeBSys, iC}, Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[1]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    Flatten@{xI, pI, TI, m1I, m2I, m3I, aI, b1I, b2I, b3I, L1I, L2I, L3I},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12,
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta"}] @@ (Flatten@{xD, pD, TEv, 
    m1Ev, m2Ev, m3Ev, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D}), {ppDim},
    Jacobian -> "FiniteDifference"];
    smallJ = D[Flatten@{Flatten[{xD, pD} - {xEv, pEv}].mJ.(Grad[H[xD, pD,{m1Ev, m2Ev, m3Ev}],
    Flatten@{xD, pD}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD}, Flatten@{xEv, pEv}}]),
    Total@(xD-xEv), Flatten[{xD, pD} - {xEv, pEv}].mJ.# & /@ (Grad[L[xD, pD], 
    Flatten@{xD, pD}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD}, Flatten@{xEv, pEv}}])},
    {Flatten@{xD, pD, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D}}] /. 
    MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{xD, pD, aD, b1D, b2D, b3D, L1D, L2D, L3D}, 
    Flatten@Flatten@{xEv, pEv, aEv, b1Ev, b2Ev, b3Ev, L1Ev, L2Ev, 
     L3Ev}}];
    Join[fluxWrap["Jacobian"[Flatten@{xEv, pEv, aEv, b1Ev, b2Ev, b3Ev, L1Ev, L2Ev, L3Ev}]] -
    Join[IdentityMatrix[ppDim], ConstantArray[0, {ppDim, 7}], 2], smallJ]
    ]
```

(The function calculates the Jacobian of the flow at $t=1$, subtracts an identity matrix (due to the fixed point), and joins the corresponding part of the conserved equations.)

```
In[3]:= Timing[JN @@ {x0B, p0B, T0B, m1B, m2B, m3B, aB, b1B, b2B, b3B, L1B, L2B, L3B}]
Out[3]:= {0.359375, <<...>>}
```

The problem now lies in that I've been unable to pass this Jacobian to `FindRoot`:

```
In[4]:= FindRoot[<<..>>, Jacobian -> JN[xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3]]

FindRoot::njnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of numbers at {xI1,yI1,zI1,xI2,yI2,zI2,xI3,yI3,zI3,pxI1,pyI1,pzI1,pxI2,pyI2,pzI2,pxI3,pyI3,pzI3,a,b1,b2,b3,L1,L2,L3} = {-1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.347111,0.532728,0.,0.347111,0.532728,0.,-0.694222,-1.06546,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}.
```

At this stage, I'm able to implement a [Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), but I'd really like to take advantage of `FindRoot`.

Here are some nice near collision continuation orbits:
[image: Near collision orbits of the three body problem]

I guess at this point, sowing the Jacobian is no longer a priority, much as it is to correctly pass it to `FindRoot`, and the overall improvement of the code.

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: "Due lack of interest" - I don't think it's that, since you got six upvotes. It just looks hard. Personally, I don't know how to trap the Jacobians used by `FindRoot[]`, and the known corresponding trick for trapping Hessians from `FindMinimum[]` doesn't work here.

Comment: @J.M. You are right. I removed the editorial comment. It's just that, being a regular here, sometimes it seems like there's no limit for what some of you can do with *MMA* :P

Comment: Maybe you can explain those nomenclatures a bit more, for example, what's figure 8 solution?

Comment: @xzczd I've edited to clarify. I hope is better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to struggle with `Jacobian`, all we need to do is to take away `Evaluated -> False` and modify the equations accordingly.

It's not clearly mentioned, but the document of `Jacobian` (it doesn't have a separate page, but is included in the document of `FindRoot`) *suggests* that, when calcuating Jacobian matrix, `FindRoot` performs symbolic differentiation if the model can be symbolically differentiated, and use finite difference if the model is a blackbox. `ParametricFunction` can be "symbolicly" differentiated, but it seems that, if `Evaluated -> False` is set, any function inside `FindRoot` will be treated as a black box.

> **Remark**
>
> 1. I think this is the reason why `Jacobian -> "FiniteDifferences"` doesn't help in this case: the warning `FindRoot::jsing` is exactly
>      the result of calculating Jacobian matrix using finite difference.
> 2. I know `Evaluated -> False` is necessary for the [`FindRoot[Print……` trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6589/1871), but now we have `EvaluationMonitor`, right?

Still, simply taking away `Evaluated -> False` will only result in warning `FindRoot::nveq`, because `Flatten@{xI, pI}` is an explicit list while `flow1 @@ Flatten@{xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}` is an implicit one, what happens here is the same as:

```
(* "lst" is supposed to become a list later *)
lst + {a, b, c}
(* {a + lst, b + lst, c + lst} *)
```

so we need to stop the auto-threading, with the `_?NumericQ` trick.

The following is the modified code. I've taken away those `AccracyGoal` because of the reason mentioned here:

[Is manual adjustment of AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal useless?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871)

```
flow1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{threeBSys, iC},
      (Flatten@{x, p})[1] // Through, {t, 0, 1}, 
      Flatten@{xI, pI, T, m1, m2, m3, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity]

(helper[##] = Flatten@{xI, pI}) & @@ ((Pattern[#, _])?NumericQ & /@ Flatten@{xI, pI});
helper // DownValues
(* {HoldPattern[
   helper[xI1_?NumericQ, yI1_?NumericQ, zI1_?NumericQ, xI2_?NumericQ, yI2_?NumericQ, 
    zI2_?NumericQ, xI3_?NumericQ, yI3_?NumericQ, zI3_?NumericQ, pxI1_?NumericQ, 
    pyI1_?NumericQ, pzI1_?NumericQ, pxI2_?NumericQ, pyI2_?NumericQ, pzI2_?NumericQ, 
    pxI3_?NumericQ, pyI3_?NumericQ, pzI3_?NumericQ]] :> {xI1, yI1, zI1, xI2, yI2, zI2, 
   xI3, yI3, zI3, pxI1, pyI1, pzI1, pxI2, pyI2, pzI2, pxI3, pyI3, pzI3}} *)

test = FindRoot[
      Flatten@{flow1 @@ Flatten@{xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3} - 
        helper @@ Flatten@{xI, pI} , 

       Flatten[{xI, pI} - {x0, p0}].mJ.(Grad[H[x, p, {1., 1., 1.}], 
            Flatten@{x, p}] /. 
          MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{x, p}, Flatten@{x0, p0}}]), Total@(xI - x0),
        Flatten[{xI, pI} - {x0, p0}].mJ.# & /@ (Grad[L[x, p], Flatten@{x, p}] /.
           MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@{x, p}, Flatten@{x0, p0}}])},
      MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {Flatten@{xI, pI, a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3}, 
        Flatten@{x0, p0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.296140, Null} *)

Norm[flow1 @@ Flatten@{xI, pI, T0, 1., 1., 1., a, b1, b2, b3, L1, L2, L3} - 
   helper @@ Flatten@{xI, pI}] /. test 

(* 1.55795*10^-13 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Playing with `NumericalFunction`, I had arrived to the conclusion that there was something fishy in the order of evaluation and that at some point, I had to use `_?NumericalQ` somewhere. I always struggle with evaluation order, accumulation of evaluations (i.e. `f[ev1][ev2]`), `=`, `:=`, etc. Curiously enough, I was able to bypass the auto-threading problem by using the fantastic characteristic of `NDSolve` to spit almost anything:`retMap = ParametricNDSolveValue[{threeBSys, iC},Through[(Flatten@{x, p})[1]]-Flatten@{xI,pI},<<..>>]`. One could even ask for the hole system!

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know the 2nd argument of `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`/`ParametricNDSolve`/`ParametricNDSolveValue` can be so flexible!