# How to evaluate the "Domain" of a Parametric Function?

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, interpolation, parametric-functions

In a simple example I try to calculate the time  the solution `x[t]` passes a second time `x[t]==1`.

```
X = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + 2 .3 x'[t] + x[t] == 1, 
x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0, flag[0] == 0
, WhenEvent[x[t] > 1 , {flag[t] -> 1}]
, WhenEvent [(x[t] < 1 ) && (flag[t] == 1) ,"StopIntegration"  ]}, 
x, {t, 0, 10}, {x0, v0}  ,DiscreteVariables -> {flag} ];
Plot[X[0, 1][t], {t, 0, X[0, 1]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]]},GridLines -> {{X[0, 1]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]]}, {1}}]
```

[image]

Depending on the initial conditions `x0,v0` I now force the endtime to equal `4` which can be visualized in

```
ContourPlot[4 == X[x0, v0]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]], {x0, -.7, .7}, {v0, 0, 2},FrameLabel -> {x0, v0}]
```

[image]

Works!
But if I try to calculate the contour for a special point

```
FindRoot[4 == X[0, v0]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]], {v0, 1}]
(*FindRoot[4 == X[0, v0]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]], {v0, 1}]*)
```

Mathematica can't evaluate!!!

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused about `["Domain"]` - it is given as a *property* for  an `InterpolatingFunction` when I use `PropertyList[ X[0,1]]` for example. But Mathematica crashes (!) doing `PropertyList[ {X[0,1], All } ]` which seems to be how `PropertyList` should be used?

Comment: Instead of `["Domain"]` you could also use `[[1]]`: `X[0, 1][[1]] (*{{0., 4.27631}}*)`

Comment: I am getting `Part::partd` errors for the `ContourPlot` (which nontheless produces a plot) and also for the `FindRoot` which also gives `FindRoot::nlnum` error.

Comment: With `Quiet@FindRoot[
  With[{v = v0}, 4 == X[0, v]["Domain"][[1, -1]]], {v0, 1}]` I am getting `{v0 -> 1.49383}`.

Comment: @gwr: Thanks, after testing your code `FindRoot[4 == X[0, v0]["Domain"][[1, -1]], {v0, 1}]` works, mysterious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Evaluated -> False`:

```
FindRoot[4 == X[0, v0]["Domain"][[1]][[-1]], {v0, 1}, Evaluated -> False]
(* {v0 -> 1.49383} *)
```

BTW, you can also add this option to `ContourPlot` to suppress the `Part::partd` warning.

Comment: (+1) Do you have a different version of the documentation? :) In other words, where to find this?

Comment: @gwr The `Evaluated` option is indeed undocumented, but it's discussed quite a bit in this site, and I just happened to read several, for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6589/1871). You can search `Evaluated` in this site to find more. :)

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be undocumented since Version 6, when it was introduced according to MathGroup post from 2007. Mathematica is not for the common sense fraction of users I guess. ;-)

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your very helpful answer, I was looking in the wrong direction for something like `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done with [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
eqns = {x''[t] + 3/5 x'[t] + x[t] == 1, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0};

sol = DSolve[eqns, x, t][[1]];
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

For `x0 == 0`

```
sol2 = NSolve[{x[4] == 1, x[t] == 1, 0 < t < 5} /. sol /. x0 -> 0, 
  {t, v0}]

(* {{v0 -> 1.49383, t -> 0.706716}, {v0 -> 1.49383, t -> 4.}} *)

ContourPlot[Evaluate[x[4] == 1 /. sol], {x0, -.7, .7}, {v0, 0, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x0, v0}),
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{0, v0} /. sol2[[1, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@{1, x[t] /. sol /. x0 -> 0 /. sol2[[1, 1]]},
 {t, 0, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, 1} /. sol2]}]
```

[image]

The interval for which `x[t] >= 1` is

```
FunctionDomain[{Sqrt[x[t] - 1] /. sol /. x0 -> 0 /. sol2[[1, 1]], 
  0 < t < 5}, t]

(* 0.706716 <= t <= 4. *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My underlying problem is much more complex  and I need to evaluate the parametric function as shown.