# Why do some uses of PropertyList crash the kernel?

Tags: bugs, interpolation, kernel, crash, properties

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.1.0**

---

While looking at the question [How to evaluate the "Domain" of an InterpolationObject?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191147/764) I noted that using [`PropertyList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyList.html) in a way, that seems to be in accordance with the documentation, will actually crash the kernel for some objects. What is going on?

Let's simply use the documentation's simple example to produce an `InterpolatingFunction` object:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]; (* creates InterpolatingFunction object *)

PropertyList[ ifun ]
```

> {Coordinates,DerivativeOrder,Domain,ElementMesh,Evaluate,GetPolynomial,Grid,InterpolationMethod,InterpolationOrder,MethodInformation,Methods,OutputDimensions,Periodicity,PlottableQ,Properties,QuantityUnits,Unpack,ValuesOnGrid}

But if we had instead executed one the following expressions we would have crashed the kernel:

> **DO NOT TRY THE FOLLOWING CODE WITHOUT HAVING SAVED YOUR WORK!**
>
> **THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL LIKELY CRASH THE KERNEL!**

```
(* PropertyList[ { ifun, 1 } ] *)

(* PropertyList[ { ifun, All } ] *)
```

Are some objects created differently than others?

Comment: On Mathematica 9, it simply fails to evaluate instead of crashing, but it definitely crashes 10.1. I'm pretty sure it's safe to call kernel crashes bugs, have you reported it to Wolfram?

Comment: Also crashes the kernel on 11.3.

Comment: I will file a bug report, thanks (and apologies for the inconvenience).