# How can the property list of interpolating function be explored and exploited?

Tags: properties

While looking at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191150), I asked myself the question given in the title. I post the results of my investigation in the question as an answer.

I used the example code given in the referenced question to carry out my investigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
f = Interpolation[pts]
```

[image: interp_func]

I extracted the property values from the property list with `PropertyValue` and made an association with the properties names as keys for ease of examination and access.

```
propAssoc = Association[{# -> PropertyValue[f, #]} & /@ PropertyList[f]]
```

[image: warning]

[image: assoc]

The association can be queried to get individual property values.

```
propAssoc @ "Domain"
```

> `{{0, 5}}`

but, of course, if we don't want the bother of making an association just to get one or a few property values, we can use

```
PropertyValue[f, "Domain"]
```

> `{{0, 5}}`

which seems always to be safe.

However, be aware that `f` itself acts like an association when given a valid property name and, also being safe, should probably be considered the standard practice for accessing properties.

```
f @ "Domain"
```

> `{{0, 5}}`

Comment: Is this meant to be sort of a canonical question/answer that we can point to whenever someone is wondering how to extract information from an `InterpolatingFunction`? And, if so, isn't the canonical answer just your very last paragraph?

Comment: @march I didn't intend for it a canonical question but as an example of how to go about finding and using the properties of functions that have them. If it is useful as a canonical that'a a bonus. However, I think the 1st part, about how extract info on the properties, is as useful as the final conclusion.

Comment: I mean, I definitely like the `Association` construction, since it has both the possible property names and their values all in one object, easily accessible and readable (rather than having to remember what properties there are). So, I get it!